# How to get llvm inline asm operands type?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, llvm, llvm-clang

I am working at a project about inline asm of LLVM, but I meet one problem about asm operands. For example, I have code like this:

```
int a;
int b;
asm("nop": "=r"(a), "r"(b), "g"(30));
```

I can get asm string "nop" using llvm::InlineAssembly::getAsmString () function, and I also can get constraints "r r imr" information using llvm::InlineAsm::ParseConstraints function and iterate the return value. But my question is I can not get asm operands information, especially asm operarands type(a is integer type, b is interger type, 30 is constant int).

So does anybody know is there any way to get asm operands information?

Answer (score 0):

In LLVM, `InlineAsm` is a subclass of `Value`, and the associated value is always of type *pointer-to-function*. The contents of that made-up function is the asm code itself.

So to get the types of the operands you analyze it just as with a pointer to function. You have a handy `FunctionType *InlineAsm::getFunctionType() const` that does half the work.

The rest is quite straightforward: `Type * FunctionType::getReturnType()` to get the output arguments and `FunctionType::params()` or similar to get the input arguments.